# centos 5.7 domu install problem on centos 5.6 dom0

Tags: xen, centos5

i'm running centos 5.6 as dom0 and want to install centos 5.7 as domu but every time i start installation the process stucks on "Starting install process.This may take several minutes..."

I install using network http method

I use xen boot images from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/images/xen/

And i'm following this guide http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/InstallingCentOSDomU

Here's my install config

```
kernel = "/srv/xen/install/centos-5.7/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/srv/xen/install/centos-5.7/initrd.img"
extra = "text"
name = "test"
memory = "512"
disk = [ 'tap:aio:/srv/xen/drive/test.img,xvda,w', ]
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0', ]
vcpus=2
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = 'destroy'
```

UPDATE*:

I've tested Centos 5.6 domu same thing

Answer (score 1):

Is this a text install (as indicated in the domU install instructions that you provided)?

Is your Xen/CentOS a fresh install from packages?

One debugging suggestion would be check that your bridge configuration is correct and that your networking on that bridge (xenbr0) is working correctly.

Using commands like:

brctl show
ifconfig -a

Post more details and we can give more hints.

This is also a fine question for the xen-users mailing list:
http://lists.xensource.com/mailman/listinfo/xen-users

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn on both of these options for it to work with centos 5.7

acpi = 1
apic = 1